# Sudo: unable to resolve host IP-17 -31-46-85- resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: resources, ip, host, restart, resolve

I was getting the following error while restarting Nginx in SSH
**Sudo: unable to resolve host IP-17-31-46-85- resource temporarily unavailable**

But the Nginx status shows running.
And while browsing my app getting like **403 forbidden error.**